# How do I group collection elements using specific grouping condition?

Tags: scala, collections

By example:

- For a list = (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9)
- I want to group elements of this list, based on the following condition:
- If x is divisible by 4, sum it up with adjacent elements
- Expected result = (1, 2, 12, 6, 23)

In java, I'd iterate over collection using for loop:

```
List<Integer> out = new ArrayList<Integer>();
for (int i = 0; i < in.size() - 2; i++)
{
    if (in.get(i+1) % 4 == 0) {
        out.add(in.get(i) + in.get(i+1) + in.get(i+2)));
        i = i + 2;
    }
    else {
        out.add(in.get(i))
    }  
}
```

Unfortunately, in Scala, I cannot do `i = i + 2`, because loop index is immutable. Is it like I have to use `while` loop for this purpose? Or maybe some clever functional way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just like in Java, you have to iterate over each element. However, instead of updating the result object each step, you return a new object each step based on the result of the previous step and the value.

The problem in your post can be solved with a fold. You give a result to start with and then apply each element to that result to get the final result.

```
val in = List(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9)
in.sliding(3).foldRight(List.empty[Int]){ (row, result) =>
    if ((row(0) % 4) == 0) {
        result
    } else if ((row(1) % 4) == 0) {
        (row(0) + row(1) + row(2)) :: result
    } else {
        row(0) :: result
    }
} toList
```

Sliding gives a "sliding view" over the List. For example: (1,2,3), (2,3,4), … I used foldRight here, because it is more efficient to add a new element to the beginning of the List instead of at the end.

You could also write a recursive function yourself to solve this problem, which applies the same principle.